# App becomes slow after sometime scrolling becomes very lagy

Tags: android, android-activity, scroll, textview

Hello i have Mainactivity in which java code is fully empty only thing i am doing in xml is using scroll view with list lf multiple textviews
But after opening Activity B with button click multiple times and than coming back to Mainactivity this makes Mainactivity scrolling very slow and lagy what should i do it is so simple code than also app is lagging badly on scrolling

Here is the code which doesnt contain much functioning than also it lags

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}
```

Here is the code of Mainactivity xml

```
<Scrollview android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content>
    <Linearlayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android: orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="First Text View"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- second TextView -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Second Text View"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Add more textviews list like this to see scrolling behaviour -->

    </Linearlayout>
</Scrollview>
```

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915654/app-is-very-slow-when-coming-back-to-main-activity)

Comment: How are you launching Activity B with a button click, if `MainActivity` doesn't contain any buttons? Please add all code for Activity B. Add all code you are using to launch Activities. Also, your other question references the same issue, but with a `GridView` instead. Please explain what code elements these two questions have in common. What are you doing that is unusual, in these two apps?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I meet the same issue now!

Answer (score -1):

**The problem**

RecyclerViews are one of the most demanding widgets on Android, and getting smooth scroll performance with complex views can be a struggle. Most devices run at a refresh rate of 60 frames per second. This means there is a new frame every ~16ms. If your app takes longer than 16ms to figure out what the next frame should display, your app skips a frame, and somewhere a puppy dies.
For more visit this [link](https://medium.com/@polson55/smooth-recyclerview-scrolling-in-android-57e7a9b71ca7)

Comment: This answer does not explain why the problem would become pronounced after repeatedly returning from another `Activity`. Also, it sounds to me like the OP is getting more than the occasional dropped frame.